# How to calculate the area of ​a quadrilateral

Tags: javascript

I can't calculate the area of ​​a quadrilateral. Do you have an idea ?
Because for the moment I can place four points to form the quadrilateral. But I would like it to reverse the air. But can't figure out how to do it. I created a js function (line Intersect Line) which prevents two straight lines from crossing ducoup thanks to that I can form a quadrilateral in all cases without the straight lines crossing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>calcul</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input class="bouton" type="button" OnClick="javascript:window.location.reload()" value="Recharger">
<div class="titre"><p>Bonjour veuillez cliquez à quatre endrois différents dans le cadre </p></div>
    <div id="example">
        <p id="test">x: , y:</p>
        <p class="nb" id="test2">vous etes à :</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cadre" id="cadre">
        <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" height="500px" width="500px" onclick="placer()">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var cursorX;
var cursorY;
let tab=[];
let tab2=[];
var cpt=0;
var lineIntersectsLine=function(line1, line2)
{
    // line1, line2= [{ x:number, y:number }, { x:number, y:number }];
    var bool=false,lines=[line1,
        line2],slope=[],offsetX=[],offsetY=[],length=[],point={ x:null,
        y:null };
    if (lines[0][1].x-lines[0][0].x===0) {
        slope[0]=(lines[0][1].y>lines[1][0].y)?Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY:Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    } else {
        slope[0]=(lines[0][1].y-lines[0][0].y)/(lines[0][1].x-lines[0][0].x);
    }
    if (lines[1][1].x-lines[1][0].x===0) {
        slope[1]=(lines[1][1].y>lines[1][0].y)?Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY:Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    } else {
        slope[1]=(lines[1][1].y-lines[1][0].y)/(lines[1][1].x-lines[1][0].x);
    }
    offsetX[0]=(slope[0]===Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ||
    slope[0]===Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY?-lines[0][0].x:0);
    offsetX[1]=(slope[1]===Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY ||
    slope[1]===Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY?-lines[1][0].x:0);
    offsetY[0]=(isFinite(slope[0]) && slope[0]!==0
            ?lines[0][0].y-slope[0]*lines[0][0].x
            :lines[0][0].y
    );
    offsetY[1]=(isFinite(slope[1]) && slope[1]!==0
            ?lines[1][0].y-slope[1]*lines[1][0].x
            :lines[1][0].y
    );
    length[0]=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lines[0][1].x-lines[0][0].x,2)+Math.pow(lines[0][1].y-lines[0][0].y,2));
    length[1]=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lines[1][1].x-lines[1][0].x,2)+Math.pow(lines[1][1].y-lines[1][0].y,2));
    if (isFinite(offsetY[0]) && isFinite(offsetY[1]) &&
        isFinite(slope[0]) && isFinite(slope[1])) {
        if (slope[0]!==slope[1]) {
            point.x=(offsetY[0]-offsetY[1])/(slope[1]-slope[0]);
            point.y=(!isNaN(slope[0]*(point.x+offsetX[0])+offsetY[0])
                    ?slope[0]*(point.x+offsetX[0])+offsetY[0]
                    :(!isNaN(slope[1]*(point.x+offsetX[1])+offsetY[1])
                            ?slope[1]*(point.x+offsetX[1])+offsetY[1]
                            :null
                    )
            );
            point.x=point.x.toFixed(3);
            point.y=point.y.toFixed(3);
        } else if (offsetY[0]===offsetY[1]) {
            point.x=null;
            point.y=null;
        }
        if (!isNaN(point.x) && !isNaN(point.y)) {
            if (point.x>=Math.min(lines[0][0].x, lines[0][1].x)
                && point.x<=Math.max(lines[0][0].x, lines[0][1].x) &&
                point.x>=Math.min(lines[1][0].x, lines[1][1].x) &&
                point.x<=Math.max(lines[1][0].x, lines[1][1].x) &&
                point.y>=Math.min(lines[0][0].y, lines[0][1].y) &&
                point.y<=Math.max(lines[0][0].y, lines[0][1].y) &&
                point.y>=Math.min(lines[1][0].y, lines[1][1].y) &&
                point.y<=Math.max(lines[1][0].y, lines[1][1].y)) {
                bool=true;
            }
        }
    } else if ((!isFinite(slope[0]) && isFinite(slope[1])) ||
        (isFinite(slope[0]) && !isFinite(slope[1]))) {
        var v=!isFinite(slope[0])?0:1;
        point.x=lines[v][0].x;
        point.y=slope[1-v]*lines[v][0].x+offsetY[1-v];
        point.x=point.x.toFixed(3);
        point.y=point.y.toFixed(3);
        if (!isNaN(point.x) && !isNaN(point.y)) {
            if (point.x>=Math.min(lines[v][0].x, lines[v][1].x)
                && point.x<=Math.max(lines[v][0].x, lines[v][1].x) &&
                point.x>=Math.min(lines[1-v][0].x, lines[1-v][1].x) &&
                point.x<=Math.max(lines[1-v][0].x, lines[1-v][1].x) &&
                point.y>=Math.min(lines[v][0].y, lines[v][1].y) &&
                point.y<=Math.max(lines[v][0].y, lines[v][1].y) &&
                point.y>=Math.min(lines[1-v][0].y, lines[1-v][1].y) &&
                point.y<=Math.max(lines[1-v][0].y, lines[1-v][1].y)) {
                bool=true;
            }
        }
    } else if (!isFinite(slope[0]) && !isFinite(slope[1])) {
        if (lines[0][0].x==lines[1][0].x &&
            lines[1][0].y>=lines[0][0].y && lines[1][0].y<=lines[0][1].y) {
            point.x=lines[0][0].x;
            point.y=lines[1][0].y;
            point.x=point.x.toFixed(3);
            point.y=point.y.toFixed(3);
            bool=true;
        }
    }
    return [bool, point];
}
function printMousePos()
{
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "x: " + cursorX + " y: " + cursorY;
}
document.onmousemove = function(e)
{
    cursorX = e.pageX;
    cursorY = e.pageY;
    printMousePos();
}
function placer()
{
    if (cpt <= 3)
    {
        tab[cpt] = [[cursorX], [cursorY]];
        let elt = document.querySelector('canvas');
        rect = elt.getBoundingClientRect();
        var node = document.createElement("span");
        var curX = cursorX - rect.left;
        var curY = cursorY - rect.top;
        tab2[cpt]={ x:curX.toFixed(3), y:curY.toFixed(3)};
        node.style.left = (cursorX - rect.left) + "px";
        node.style.top = (cursorY - rect.top) + "px";
        document.getElementById("canvas").parentNode.appendChild(node);
        cpt++;
        document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = " vous etes a :" +
            cpt + " clic";
        var lines = [];
        if(tab[3] != null)
        {
            for (var i=0;i<=3;i++)
            {
                for (var y=i+1;y<=3;y++)
                {
                    if(i!=y)
                    {
                        lines.push([tab2[i], tab2[y], [i,y]]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
            {
                for (var y=i+1;y<lines.length;y++)
                {
                    test = lineIntersectsLine(lines[i], lines[y]);
                    if (!test[0])
                    {
                        var points = lines[i][2].concat(lines[y][2]);
                        var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
                        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.fillStyle="rgb(213,186,186)"
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        console.log(points);
                        for(var j =0;j<points.length;j++) {
                            if (j==0)
                            {
                                ctx.moveTo(tab2[points[j]].x, tab2[points[j]].y);
                            }
                            else if(j<points.length)
                            {
                                ctx.lineTo(tab2[points[j]].x, tab2[points[j]].y);
                            }
                        }
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.fill();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function aire()
{

}
```

rouver comment faire merci.

Comment: Please note that the script is in the header and will run before the DOM is ready. Meaning that `document.whatever` functions will return `null`. Consider either putting the `defer` attribute onto it, wait for a page load type event, or put the script at the end of the body?

Comment: the line length formula is `len = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)`. The area formula for a quadrilateral is `(w * h)`